# Animate toggle margin-left of div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to mimic others' code but with no luck. How can I get Div1 to toggle margin-left:30% when DivButton is clicked? Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/3nc62rec/

HTML

```
<div id="Div1"></div>
<br><br>
<div id="DivButton"></div>
```

CSS

```
#Div1{
    background:blue;
    width:50%;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:0%;
}

#DivButton{
    background:green;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

JS

```
$('#DivButton').click(function(){                

});


/* 
var toggleWidth = $("#Div1").width() == 365 ? "98%" : "365px"; 
$('#Div1').animate( {'width': toggleWidth}, 300, resize); 
*/

/* 
var toggleMargin = $("#Div1").marginLeft() == 30% ? "10%" : "30%"; 
$('#Div1').animate( {'margin-left': toggleMargin}, 300, resize); 
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $div1 = $('#Div1')
$('#DivButton').click(function() {
  $div1.toggleClass('isOut')
  var isOut = $div1.hasClass('isOut')
  $div1.animate({marginLeft: isOut ? '30%' : '0'}, 300)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nc62rec/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jquery animation.

```
  $('#DivButton').animate({marginleft: "30%"}, 500);
```

Comment: I think he realizes that? It's in his source code, commented out

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#DivButton').click(function () {
    $("#Div1").animate({
        marginLeft: '30%'
    }, 500);
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3nc62rec/4/)**